# How can I share my clipboard content between a Mac and a PC?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac

Is it possible to share clipboard content between a Mac and a PC running Windows 7?

Comment: Similar question https://superuser.com/questions/1489987/cross-platform-tool-for-clipboard-sharing with a suggestion for https://www.fossmint.com/clipboard-anywhere-a-multi-platform-clipboard-app/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I do it all the time with Synergy
 http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/ its an open source application that allows you to use 1 keyboard and mouse on mutable computers even if there running different OS's. It also will carry you clipbord info from 1 computer to another.

Comment: I was aware of this option although personally I would go with the newer and active project http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/ but I was hoping for something that was 'just' clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is [shareclip](http://homepage.mac.com/bnej/shareclip/).

Install it on both the Mac and PC. Connect from one to the other via IP. Copying on one instantly shares it to the other machines clip-board. Super easy.

Comment: The link is dead, but shareclip is still out there if you do a little Googling: http://share-clip.softpedia.com/

Comment: Both links are dead. Perhaps this is the new one - https://github.com/khrj/shareclip

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/debauchee/barrier (free & open source) or https://symless.com/synergy (paid).

Answer (score 1):

What about a shared [Google Document](http://docs.google.com/), or [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) which works like a charm (for sure you don't really share a clipboard, but you can access this shared space easily from both computers).

Answer (score 0):

The only cross-platform solution I'm aware of, besides Synergy, is [CrossClip](http://www.stretchedout.com/products/crossclip/crossclip.php). I have no experience with it, and I don't know if it's compatible with Windows 7 or the latest versions of MacOS X. It appears that it hasn't been updated in a while, but maybe it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Another web-based not quite clipboard but maybe good enough: [Cl1p.net](http://cl1p.net) — and if you are a quicksilver user there is a plugin...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Remote Desktop will do that for you. The Mac client is free. Download that, sit in front of the Mac, and have a remote Windows desktop. Enjoy copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Put your clipboard content on the cloud and keep them protected by password: [iPaste](http://www.ipaste.eu) or [evernote](http://evernote.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [this little web clipboard](http://ipshare.net/)... Really helpfull for simple text and links!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Google Chrome's [Clipboard Sync extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipboard-sync/dapdfappilfdiljfpjcbkmkblldaemjg/related).

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping for a better solution, but for now I just have a dedicated note in the Notes app on Mac. On Windows I log into to the same Apple account on [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) and open the note on the web version of the Notes app. Sync is automatic, but you may need to refresh the page to speed things up.

As an alternative, you could also have a dedicated file on your Windows PC which you access via SMB, but I would only suggest this if you intend to share files via SMB between both machines, since it requires a bit more work.

By the way, long time ago, I've used a free tool to share the keyboard, mouse and clipboard between machines and it was pretty good. Used to be free then. Not sure about the name, but I think it was [Synergy](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core). According to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1744140/668905) I upvoted, there seems to be a free alternative, but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score -1):

If you connect from one to the other via [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) you can, I believe.  Otherwise, in what context would you want to do this?