# Cross-platform tool for clipboard sharing?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, clipboard, cross-platform

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to share the clipboard between multiple systems operating within a LAN. The requirements I have are:

- It can run on Windows, macOS, and Linux
- Sharing is automatic: as soon as a user on one system copies something, it automatically shares it to the other systems

Are there any tools that can do this?

I'll note that I am aware of [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy), which often is recommended for this sort of thing, but Synergy is meant for sharing a single keyboard and mouse between multiple systems and it doesn't look like you can use it *only* for its clipboard sharing functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally tried this yet, but have a look at [Clipboard Anywhere](https://www.fossmint.com/clipboard-anywhere-a-multi-platform-clipboard-app/).